# How to do a hypothesis test for gender proportions in a population?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution

Suppose I have 50 students -> with 30M and 20F. My hypothesis is that p1(males) = p2(females) with p1 and p2 being the proportions. I'm completely new to statistics so I'm a little confused. I understand that it is a BAD idea to do the Chi-Square test here. Since these are categorical variables should I use the Binomial test? All the examples for the binomial test that I've seen have the sample and the control population. What would the control population be in this case? Could be a population that I 'invent' with 25 males and 25 females? I could then test proportion of males is equal in the sample and the control to verify or reject my original hypothesis?

Guidance would be appreciated!